# How the supremum of a function and its derivative in the unit interval are related in normed spaces

Tags: calculus, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E=\{ f: \,f\in C^1([0,1]), f(0)=0\}$ and the norm defined on $E$ be $$ \left\|f\right\|_E = \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \,|f'(x)|,\,\, f\in E, $$ and $F=C\,([0,1])$ with the norm $$ \left\|f\right\|_F = \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \,|f(x)|,\,\, f\in F.$$

I need to prove that $\forall f\in E, $ $$  \left\|f\right\|_F \leq  \left\|f\right\|_E.$$

Since the interval $[0,1]$ is compact, $f\in E, f'\in F$ are continuous, the maxima of these functions are attained in the unit intarval. Thus, $\exists x_1, x_2\in [0,1]$ such that we can write: $$ \left\|f\right\|_F= \max_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|=|f(x_1)| \,\,\text{and}\,\,\left\|f\right\|_E= \max_{x\in [0,1]}|f'(x)|=|f'(x_2)|.$$ Also, $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h +o(h)$. After taking the norm and using the triangle inequality I can not reach the point which would suggest me the solution.

Can you provide a solution proposal or give me a hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track. Let $x_1 \in [0,1]$ such that $|f(x_1)| = \|f\|_F$.

If $x_1 = 0$ then $f \equiv 0$ so the statement holds.

If $x_1 > 0$, the mean value theorem implies that $\exists c \in \langle 0, x_1\rangle$ such that
$$f(x_1) - f(0) = f'(c)(x_1 - 0)$$
so
$$\|f\|_F = |f(x_1)| = |f'(c)||x_1| \le |f'(c)| \le \|f\|_E$$

Comment: Many thanks. It looks so easy and yet I could not make it.

Comment: Under the same conditions can you give me a hint to prove that the function $s(f)=f'+f²$ is differentiable.

Comment: @user249018 The differential of $s : E \to F$ at point $f \in E$ should be given by $Ds(f)h := h' + 2fh$.
Indeed, it is bounded with $\|Ds(f)\| \le 1+2\|f\|_E$ and
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|s(f+h) - s(f) - Ds(f)h\|_F}{\|h\|_E}&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|s(f+h) - s(f) - Ds(f)h\|_F}{\|h\|_E}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|f'+h' +(f+h)^2- f'-f^2 - h'-2fh\|_F}{\|h\|_E}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|h^2\|_F}{\|h\|_E}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|h\|_F^2}{\|h\|_E}\\
&\le \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|h\|_E^2}{\|h\|_E}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \|h\|_E\\
&= 0
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. How you come to define the differential in such a way ? I tried it with $Ds(f):=2f$ but did not work, thats why I needed some support. Is it very obvious or one should try different options such that the rest of the first order Taylor development become negligeable in respect to the function $h$ ? Anyway thank you for the very clear answer.

Comment: @user249018 I tried to define it such that $s(f+h) - s(f) - Ds(f)h = o(h^2)$, it was mostly trial and error.